# A question related to past tense

Tags: tense, past-tense

Yesterday I read a novel and in that novel, I noticed a sentence that got me confused. The sentence is, "Everyone who had partied last night had a hangover."

Since "last night" is like a  point of time is it possible to use had+v3 in this sentence?

Comment: You seem to be assuming there's something "wrong" with using Past Perfect when talking about a *specified* point in time earlier than the "narrative reference time" (where in your example, the narrative reference time is the morning after the party). If so, you are mistaken -
 there's nothing wrong with, for example, *I ignored John at the party last night because he **had** insulted me at last year's party*. Many people wouldn't bother with ***had*** there, but that's just because it's effectively *unnecessary*, not because it's *wrong* (and we *tend* to use simpler tenses wherever we can).

Comment: It may also be worth pointing out that the cited example could have been rephrased as *Everyone who had partied last night **was hung over***. Native speakers know without thinking about it that ***had*** in Simple Past *had a hangover* is completely different to ***had*** in Past Perfect *had partied*. They wouldn't see anything unusual about using the same word in two different ways within a single sentence like that - the main reason people might discard the first instance in your example is that where two verb forms are "acceptable", we usually prefer to use the simpler one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not clear whether you are asking whether "had partied" is correct, or if you should use "had+v3" with "to have a hangover".  Example:

> Everyone who partied last night, **had had** a hangover by the time they awoke.

This is perfectly valid English.  It's not common to use multiple *hads* in a row, because usually one will do, but you can make up all kinds of fun sentences using the past and present perfect with "to have".

> James, while John had had "had," had had "had had"; "had had" had had a better effect on the teacher.  [(explanation)](http://www.businessinsider.com/weird-sentences-2014-1)

Comment: And that "that that" that [that](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/108402/how-to-avoid-that-that-that-that-is-so-very-awkward) question has isn't really all that awkward at all.

Answer (score 2):

It's definitely OK for common usage-- no native speaker would complain about the sentence, or think it odd. I don't think that the past perfect is required here (as per FumbleFingers' comment). But if I were trying to justify it in context I would make the argument that the partying from last night, though completed, continues to be relevant into the next morning because it caused (or at least facilitated) the hangovers.